# How do I get this more... text to change after a slideToggle() has happened, using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this piece of JQuery:

```
$('.myAuctionPanel h3').click(function(){

        $(this).next().slideToggle();

        $(this).children().text("more...");
});
```

This is what happens so far...when I click on the `<h3>` a div underneath it does a slideToggle(). Inside the `<h3>` I have a `<span>` which then shows the 'more...' text.

My question is when I click the `<h3>` again how do I get the text inside the span to change to 'less...'?

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function, which accepts multiple arguments.  These are functions that are called in turn upon `click` events:

```
$('.myAuctionPanel h3').toggle(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();

    $(this).children().text("more...");
}, function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();

    $(this).children().text("less...");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a trillion...I knew something was missing but couldn't pinpoint it